# What is "Web of Science Author Connect" and what are the benefits of opting-in?

Tags: web-of-science

I am always skeptical of unsolicited emails, and I have never heard of this service.

I have received an email from the Web of Science Group offering the following because I have published an article:

- Call for Papers requests from scholarly publishers
- News related to your field of research
- Information about journals and books in your areas of interest
- New scientific applications relevant to your field of research

Has anybody used this service? It seems like a newsletter to me for than anything useful for my research, maybe the first point might be useful.

Comment: Have you tried looking at their website?

Comment: @SolarMike yes, it seems a data mining company associated with WoS. Can't really understand the utility for researchers.